# Traits: why do I need 'insteadof' when 'as' is used?

Tags: php

PHP 7.1

```
use DatedTaskTypeTrait, LengthedTaskTypeTrait {
    DatedTaskTypeTrait::addFields as addDatedFields;
    LengthedTaskTypeTrait::addFields as addLengthedFields;
}
```

Gives:

> Fatal error: Trait method addFields has not been applied, because there are collisions with other trait methods

Why? I gave them different names and there must be no conflict anymore. Why I have to add the useless line? :

```
 use DatedTaskTypeTrait, LengthedTaskTypeTrait {
    DatedTaskTypeTrait::addFields insteadof LengthedTaskTypeTrait;
    DatedTaskTypeTrait::addFields as addDatedFields;
    LengthedTaskTypeTrait::addFields as addLengthedFields;
}
```

That's nonsense...

Comment: It may have something to do with backward compatibility for the autoload.  Not sure, but that sort-of seems like it could matter.  Are you able to get it working with your second example?  The docs are pretty clear: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

Comment: Second example works, of course.